# Update panel not working when validation group is used

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have following thing in update panel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAddProduct" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCaption" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        :
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" ValidationGroup="NewValues"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="regInvData" ControlToValidate="txtValue" ErrorMessage="*"
                            runat="server" ValidationGroup="NewValues"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdColType" />
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnSku" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
                            ValidationGroup="NewValues" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When i click on submit button in above code, `btnSubmit_Click` does not gets called.

When i removes  `ValidationGroup="NewValues"`

function gets called.

Before keeping it in update panel everything was working fine.

How to use validationgroup in above case ?

Please help me.

Comment: I can see javascript error in your code. the closing tag of update panel should be  `</asp:UpdatePanel> `

Comment: make a trigger of that button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
<td align="left">
<asp:Label ID="lblCaption" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td align="left">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" ValidationGroup="NewValues"> 
 </asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="regInvData" ControlToValidate="txtValue"
ErrorMessage="*"
 runat="server" ValidationGroup="NewValues"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdColType" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnSku" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">&nbsp;
</td>
<td align="left">
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" 
OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"  ValidationGroup="NewValues"
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It works for me